Azure Devops -Branches
How to set bypass policy permissions? Why do I still see policy failures in the pull request status?
In Azure Devops if we have created 3 or more branches like Dev, qa and prod and if we did set up any branch policies and we are not applying any policies on Dev but applied policies on qa and prod dev but to send files to qa and prod we need to send or create pull request from dev.
Is there any way to modify any changes in prod directly with out waiting to make changes in prod?


is there any way to modify any changes in prod directly with out waiting to make changes in prod.

Based on your description, the qa and prod branch have branch policy and you want to directly make changes to prod branch.
To meet your requirement, you can grant the permission: Bypass policies when pushing to user account in Project Settings -> Repositories -> Target Repo -> Security.

If you only want to set the permission at Repo branch level, you can select the branch name in Repo security and set the Bypass policies when pushing permission.
For example:

Set permission at branch level:

In this case, you can directly push the files to target repo.
For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: Bypass branch policies
